# GNU assembler Macros

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, osdev

I am trying to build a simple macro in GNU assembler (2.26.1) (gcc 5.4.0) but getting some error after several interactions: **Invalid character '(' in mnemonic**

I've tried to follow the advice at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html with \() or & but no luck.

```
    .macro macro_gen_irqh isrb, isre
    _irq_entry_\isrb\():
        cli
        call isr_common_handler
        .if  \isre-\isrb
           macro_gen_irqh    "(\isrb+1)",\isre
       .endif
    .endm
```

If I replace the label _irq_entry_\isrb(): to "(\isrb)": it does work for the enumeration but without the required full label name.

The end result should be:

```
_irq_entry_0:
   cli
   call isr_common_handler
_irq_entry_1:
.
.
_irq_entry_2:
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks it does the work. I actually tried the .altmacro, but missed the % on the macro param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `.altmacro` directive you can rewrite it this way:

```
.altmacro

.macro macro_gen_irqh isrb, isre
_irq_entry_\isrb:
    call isr_common_handler
    .if \isre-\isrb
        macro_gen_irqh %isrb+1,\isre
    .endif
.endm
```

[`altmacro`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Altmacro.html) makes a number of changes, but an important one is that if you use `%` on a macro parameter it is treated as an expression and the result is returned as a string. I take advantage of that in this line:

```
macro_gen_irqh %isrb+1,\isre
```

The result of `macro_gen_irqh 0 1` would be:

```
_irq_entry_0:
    call isr_common_handler

_irq_entry_1:
    call isr_common_handler
```